# Xamarin Forms, best way to navigate from AppDelegate to a screen in forms?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.forms, appdelegate

When I receive a push notification with Custom Data, based on the data available in it, I need to make a call to navigate the user to a certain screen in Xamarin Forms.

```
 public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        // This is where I need to navigate the user to a form based screen 
    }
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

ST

Comment: Need more info. Are you using NavigationPage in your app? Then Navigation.PushAsync(new yourScreen());

Comment: The question is not about navigation between screens in xamarin forms but from iOS AppDelegate to Xamarin Forms screen.

Comment: If you are using navigation you can use  App.Current.MainPage.Navigation to push/pop required page